# Eclipse Failing to start

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.6, helios

For some reason my eclipse is failing to start in Windows 7.

from the error log it does looks like Eclipse is failing to create a directory.

I tried starting eclipse with

```
    eclipse.exe -debug -consolelog
```

but this did not help me in seeing which directory it actually failed while creating.

I am using eclipse Helios

Exception Message is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-10-01 10:05:58.089
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/team/filesystem/ui/UiPlugin
    at com.ibm.team.metronome.internal.VisibilityController.updateVisibility(VisibilityController.java:53)
    at com.ibm.team.metronome.internal.MetronomeWidget.fill(MetronomeWidget.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimBarManager2$STrimBuilder.renderTrim(TrimBarManager2.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimBarManager2$STrimBuilder.processAdditions(TrimBarManager2.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimBarManager2$STrimBuilder.build(TrimBarManager2.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.TrimBarManager2.update(TrimBarManager2.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3834)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setLayoutDataForContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:3847)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.createDefaultContents(WorkbenchWindowConfigurer.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.createWindowContents(WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.createContents(WorkbenchWindow.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$22.runWithException(Workbench.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui (139).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.ibm.team.filesystem.ui.UiPlugin.start() of bundle com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.restproxy.Discovery2$PermissionUtilsRegistrySecurityException: com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.internal.utils.IPermissionUtil$CannotCreateException
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.restproxy.Discovery2.secure(Discovery2.java:834)
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.restproxy.Discovery2.startInProcess(Discovery2.java:760)
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.restproxy.Discovery2.createDaemon(Discovery2.java:716)
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.restproxy.Discovery2.resolve(Discovery2.java:600)
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.ui.UiPlugin.start(UiPlugin.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.internal.utils.IPermissionUtil$CannotCreateException
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.internal.HardcodedPermissionUtils.mkRoot(HardcodedPermissionUtils.java:181)
    at com.ibm.team.filesystem.client.restproxy.Discovery2.secure(Discovery2.java:832)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: have you try to add this class to you path o maven pom? maybe is another kind of error, but this will be an easy solution.

Comment: Have you tried running it as administrator? mkRoot suggests to me it is trying to elevate permissions and failing.

Comment: @ZaoTaoBao sorry did not understand what you mean, the jar is already in the class path.

Comment: @Caleryn, yes I tried as administrator but some error. It did worked fine before, but stopped all of the sudden

Comment: uff..i was looking for and find this:It can as I'm sure you realize be caused by many things. One thing can be that you need to run the eclipse or the eclipse installation as administrator on windows. Another solution could be to download the zipped version and just copy in the content in your existing eclipse library. A third option could be to install RTC client using IBM IM and then add your personal plugins to that afterwards. (Its no problem having multiple eclipse installations on your machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution

A. Delete Folder:

> ${Eclipse-home}\plugins\com.ibm.team.filesystem.ide.ui_2.1.0.v20101110_2353

B. Start eclipse(now eclipse will start just fine)

C. reinstall the plugin

underlying issue still unknown :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a permissions problem. Please re-install and make sure your normal user has permission to access the app directories and execute.

As a debug install it in a custom folder (not in program files folder) and if possible on a different drive the windows drive (like say D:. E:\ etc). If you do not have other drives, create a different folder and then try installing and see if it works.